# Can not get morningstar to work with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

page: https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/VTWIX/portfolio

It has an ID named styleWeight. Which gives result when I query it from the browser console; `document.querySelectorAll("#styleWeight")`

But I am getting `catch error Error: No element found for selector: #styleWeight` when I try the same in below:

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const fundUrlOnMorningstar = `https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/VTWIX/portfolio`;
   
    await page.goto(fundUrlOnMorningstar, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

    
    const weightSelector = '#styleWeight';
    page.waitForSelector(weightSelector);
    await page.click(weightSelector);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see any results when I run `document.querySelectorAll(".square-text")` by hand in the browser dev tools on my end. What data are you expecting to get as output?

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, I need to click on a button before I see that selector. I am struggling with clicking on that button and have updated the question with the detail.

Comment: I don't see any `.click()` calls in your code. `page.waitForSelector(weightSelector);` must be awaited.

Comment: I did not include that statement as I was getting error with waitForSelector() before that, I updated the question with that statement.

Comment: Thanks, but you're still missing `await page.waitForSelector(weightSelector)`. That `await` has to be there. If you have the `await` and it's still failing, try running headfully and adding a user agent and see if that works.